# "Street workout" : est-il répandu ?

Tags: anglais, sport

> -Où tu vas ?

> -Je vais faire du [*street workout*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_workout).

Peut-on utiliser couramment la tournure "*street workout*" ?

Comment: Certainement plus compris que callisthénie, mais ça dépend des milieux.  Familièrement je pense qu'un Français ira faire ses exercices physiques, son fitness (que même ceux qui ne parlent pas anglais emploient), son entraînement, etc.

Comment: Le franglais ou l'utilisation de l'anglais en français n'est pas décidé par décret. Chacun dit ce que bon lui semble. Bien des fois, un terme commence sa vie avec plusieurs possibilités et fini ailleurs. courrier électronique se dit souvent "mél" En anglais, on dit parkour, un terme français qui est dèjà rentré dans les moeurs.

Comment: Street workout n'est pas "répandu" en anglais non plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Peut-on utiliser couramment la tournure "street workout" ?

Couramment en France, sûrement pas. C'est trop récent et pas assez populaire pour être connu du grand public.

Quasiment tout le monde comprendra ***street*** mais ***workout*** n'est pas un mot très enseigné en cours d'anglais ni très courant dans les expressions anglaises auxquelles on est habitué. ***Workout*** évoquera soit rien du tout, soit ***work*** et ***out*** : "travailler dehors". Il ne faudra donc compter que sur le contexte pour évaluer la probabilité de compréhension de la phrase.

1. Si la personne à qui on s'adresse est adepte de cette activité, il y a une chance qu'elle connaisse l'expression ***street workout*** ou simplement ***workout*** donc on pourra utiliser l'expression sans crainte d'être incompris.
2. Si, lorsqu'on prononce cette phrase, il est clair qu'on s'apprête à faire du sport (vêtements, chaussures, brassard pour son téléphone, etc.), la personne se doutera bien qu'il s'agit d'aller faire de l'exercice dehors et ne posera probablement pas de question.
3. Si rien ne permet de deviner l'activité à venir, on aura en revanche probablement droit à la question:
   — ***Tu vas faire du quoi ??***
   et il ne te restera qu'à expliquer de quoi il s'agit, dire par exemple que c'est un peu comme la muscu, mais libre, en extérieur, avec les agrès plus ou moins prévus pour qu'on peut y trouver.

Comme l'a commenté None, c'est tout de même bien mieux qu'avec *Je vais faire de la callisthénie* où la question — ***Tu vas faire de la quoi ??*** sera largement majoritaire, même dans le cas où on va visiblement faire du sport.

Note: La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/index.aspx) ne propose pas de traduction de *street workout*, ni même de *workout* tout court, l'[OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26557978) propose une traduction aussi présente chez France Terme (cf. réponse de Lambie) (**entraînement de rue**) mais elle ne semble pas avoir beaucoup de succès (0 hits sur Google pour *je fais de l'entraînement de rue* ou *je vais faire de l'entraînement de rue*). Il semble que les adeptes français utilisent plus le mot anglais (49 hits sur Google pour **je fais du street workout**) ou son abréviation SWO, qui font certainement plus "branchés" qu'« entraînement de rue ». Je doute donc que cette dernière expression ait un avenir en France.

[Exemple 1](https://meco.bzh/fitness-swo-parcours-sportifs/):

> Le Street Work Out (SWO) — appelé aussi Calisthenics ou Callisthénie — est une discipline récente inspirée des exercices de musculation classiques et de mouvements acrobatiques freestyle.

Exemple 2 ([dialogue sur un forum de traders](https://www.andlil.com/forum/file-scalping-et-day-trading-du-vendredi-12-fevrier-2021-t41910-100.html)), février 2021

> — Tu pratiques quel sport ?
> — Je fais du street workout, une sorte de gymnastique mais avec les moyens du bord (barre de traction, anneaux, une aire de jeux etc.)
> — Ok dans le genre crossfit ou freeletics en gros ?
> — Non du tout c'est plutôt des figures statiques ou dynamiques, style croix de fer, drapeau, planche, front lever, des 360 a la barre etc. etc.
> — Ok je vois !

Comment: Workout n'est pas un mot enseigné en cours d'anglais?? Le problème est ceci: Voulez-vous oui ou non utilser le franglais ou l'anglais? Les mots anglais rentrent dans les usages par plusieurs chemins. Et c'est notoire: les traders parlent franglais et utilisent des mots anglais plus que toute autre profession puisque les intruments financiers avec lesquels ils jouent viennent des Etats-unis. Et puis, on vient d'avoir un mot français nouveau en anglais: parkour. Et c'est la seule façon de le dire.

Comment: @Lambie 1. Ne me fais pas dire autre chose que ce que j'ai écrit. 2. Il n'y a pas que des traders qui font du *street workout* et qui l'appellent comme ça.

Comment: La question est mal posée. Quand un terme est nouveau, parfois il finit ailleurs. Par exemple: courrier électronique a fini par se dire: mél//faire de l'entraînement de rue va certainement finir par se dire: **faire du street**.  Le génie du français (haha) dans la rue est très sympa. Et c'est trop tôt pour savoir.

Comment: La question est très claire. Elle ne demande pas une traduction ou des spéculations sur le futur de cette expression. Elle demande s'il est possible **aujourd'hui** d'utiliser couramment cette expression. Il ne s'agit bien sûr pas de savoir si on est autorisé à le dire (on a le droit de dire à peu près ce qu'on veut en France) mais si on peut le faire sans (gros) risque d'être incompris.

Comment: Le terme est assez nouveau (même en anglais). Mais si on regarde la tendance historique dans ce domaine le terme est trop long.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est ce qu'un terme "trop long" au regard d'une tendance historique ?

Comment: Cela veut dire que les trucs longs (deux or trois mots) finissent par se raccourcir dans le language populaire/parlé. Même en anglais, ils vont dire: I'm a street guy, pour street workout guy. La même tendance s'avère en français. Jouer au foot, au lieu de jouer au football.

Comment: Ah, d'accord. Oui, *faire du street* est une expression qui existe probablement déjà parmi les adeptes de la chose. Je viens d'interroger quelques adolescents autour de moi et aucun ne connaissait le sens du mot *workout* alors que tous comprennent le mot *training*, comme quoi, il ne fait pas partie du vocabulaire de base enseigné dans le secondaire.

Answer (score 3):

**entraînement de rue**
**Journal officiel du 10/01/2020**
Domaine :
SPORTS

> Définition : Pratique sportive visant au développement musculaire, qui
> consiste à enchaîner de façon soutenue des exercices de force, de
> résistance, de souplesse et d’équilibre, à l’aide d’éléments de
> mobilier urbain et sans utiliser d’autre charge que le poids du corps.

> Équivalent étranger : street workout (en)

[Ministère de la culture](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/SPOR472)

[Chaque fois qu'il y a un terme en anglais avec une traduction "officielle" sur des sites officiels , on trouve la mention "équivalent étranger", quand c'est presque toujours en anglais. "faire du street" actuellement se dit pour le sport connu comme BMX street.]

[Une prédiction non-officielle: dans quelques années on finira par dire: faire du street. Comme faire un footing.]

Voici une liste des mots empruntés à l'anglais:

[reinvented by the French](https://www.thelocal.fr/20161006/english-words-stolen-and-reinvented-by-the-french/)

Comment: Entraînement de rue est aussi ce que recommande l'OQLF: [http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26557978](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26557978).

Answer (score -1):

Bien sûr que l'on peut, c'est une structure tout à fait correcte.

Le terme "workout" s'est déjà répandu en France, maintenant "street workout" est en progression dans les charts.

Est-ce une bonne chose ?
Je ne sais pas.

Est-ce un fait ? Manifestement

Comment: Est-ce qu'on a des exemples d'usage? à l'oral? dans la presse ? Autant *workout* me semble connu, autant c'est la première fois que je lis *street workout*

Comment: Un exemple courant serait : "J'ai finis mon workout de la journée" ou encore "Je dois faire mon workout".
Quant au "street workout", j'avoue ne pas l'utiliser personnellement mais j'ai des connaissances qui n'ont pas peur d'user de la syntaxe.

Comment: Quand on dit j'ai fini mon *workout* (si on le dit...) ça veut dire que j'ai fini mon entraînement, pas spécialement mon entraînement de rue ou en salle ou à la piscine...

Comment: Le plus souvent cela désigne un entrainement en salle, toujours est-il que le terme workout s'est démocratisé...

Comment: Démocratisé peut être d'abord parmi les personnes qui disent aussi *en progression dans les charts*. Je n'avais jamais entendu *charts* autrement que pour les classement musicaux (top 50, etc.)